To handle null check when using max() in Mule 4 DW 2.0
I am trying to get the latest end date from the below payload using max() which is working fine but there are chances that the endDate might be empty or elements itself might not be present in the response so want to know how to handle the null check before getting the maximum endDate value
input Payload
{
    "cid": "567",
    "payload": {
        "id": "34567",
        "employee": {
            "employType": "PartTime",
            "positions": [
                {
                    "role": "Mulesoft Developer",
                    "startDate": "2023-06-09",
                    "endDate": "2024-02-22"
                },
                {
                    "role": "Senior Mulesoft Developer",
                    "startDate": "2024-02-23",
                    "endDate": "2024-09-30"
                }
            ],
            "Clevel": "987654"
        }
    }
}

Below DW is used to get the maximum endDate and used further in the flow.
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var latestEndDate = max(payload.payload.employee.positions.endDate)

---
latestEndDate

Input Payload with empty endDate
{
            "cid": "567",
            "payload": {
                "id": "34567",
                "employee": {
                    "employType": "PartTime",
                    "positions": [
                        {
                            "role": "Mulesoft Developer",
                            "startDate": "2023-06-09",
                            "endDate": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "role": "Senior Mulesoft Developer",
                            "startDate": "2024-02-23",
                            "endDate": ""
                        }
                    ],
                    "Clevel": "987654"
                }
            }
        }

expected out:

null
input payload without endDate
 {
                "cid": "567",
                "payload": {
                    "id": "34567",
                    "employee": {
                        "employType": "PartTime",
                        "positions": [
                            {
                                "role": "Mulesoft Developer",
                                "startDate": "2023-06-09"
                            
                            },
                            {
                                "role": "Senior Mulesoft Developer",
                                "startDate": "2024-02-23"
                                
                            }
                        ],
                        "Clevel": "987654"
                    }
                }
            }

expected out:
null

Your inputs are invalid JSON. There is a missing comma. There is no difference between the last two inputs. Please edit and fix the question. What is you expected output for each case? Add them to the question too.

@aled updated now.

You can apply a filter check to check for empty string as well as no field present
Input
{
    "cid": "567",
    "payload": {
        "id": "34567",
        "employee": {
            "employType": "PartTime",
            "positions": [
                {
                    "role": "Mulesoft Developer",
                    "startDate": "2023-06-09",
                    "endDate": "2024-02-22"
                    
                },
                {
                    "role": "Mulesoft Developer",
                    "startDate": "2023-06-09"
                    
                },
                {
                    "role": "Senior Mulesoft Developer",
                    "startDate": "2024-02-23",
                    "endDate": ""
                }
            ],
            "Clevel": "987654"
        }
    }
}

DW
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var latestEndDate = max(payload.payload.employee.positions.endDate filter (!isEmpty($)))
---
latestEndDate


I updated the above to include default to it incase the input payload doesn't has any endDate for any of the positions, in that case variable will be assigned null.
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var latestEndDate = max(payload.payload.employee.positions.endDate filter (!isEmpty($))  default [])
latestEndDate
@karthik

@Sunny85 so it worked for you right?

Yes it worked as expected
